# Python REGEX - Select a single instance of timecode that it appears prior to a parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

Example (this is a line that is a string of text:

```
Title of item: 1:33 + 4:55 + 4:32 (this is a note about 4:32) + 5:27 (another "note", I want to keep 3:22-4:50 from 5:27)
```

So in this instance I'd like to select 4:32 and 5:27 and create a dictionary looking like this:

```
{clip: 4:32, notes: 'this is a note about 4:32'}
{clip: 5:27, notes: 'another "note", I want to keep 3:22-4:50 from 5:27'}
```

I am trying to determine the best possible regex to write that selects the instance of timecode that appears before a parenthesis and only grabbing the timecode that appears before the parenthesis and creates a key value pair in a dictionary along with a second key value pair that takes what is inside the parenthesis and inserts it as a string into the value of the second key value pair.

Comment: Are you trying to create one single dictionary or multiple dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall(pattern, txt)` to find all occurrences of your pattern:

```
import re 

s = 'Title of item: 1:33 + 4:55 + 4:32 (this is a note about 4:32) + 5:27 (another "note", I want to keep 3:22-4:50 from 5:27)'

pattern = r"(\d+:\d+) \((.*?)\)"

match = re.findall(pattern, s)

print(dict(match))
# outputs:
# {'4:32': 'this is a note about 4:32', 
# '5:27': 'another "note", I want to keep 3:22-4:50 from 5:27'}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer in order to "close" this question :)